# Generalize 1 dimensional conditional PDF to n dimensional conditional PDF

Tags: statistics

Let there be the continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$. Assume we are given $f_{X, Y}$.

We can say that...

$$f_{Y}(y) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx$$

and we can also say that...

$$f_{X}(x | Y=y) = \frac {f_{X, Y}(x, y)} {f_{y}(y)}$$

Now let there be the random vectors $\vec X$ and $\vec Y$ which respectively have i.i.d. elements distributed like $X$ and $Y$ respectively. And let $\vec X$ and $\vec Y$ both be of length $k$.

Can we write $f_{\vec X}(\vec x | \vec Y = \vec y)$ in terms of $f_{X}(x | Y=y)$ and $k$?

If it is unclear what $\vec X$ and $\vec Y$ are, then here is an example...

Let $X \sim N(6,3)$ and $Y \sim N(2,15)$ and let $k = 3$. Then $\vec{X}$ would be $\begin{bmatrix}X_1 & X_2 & X_3\end{bmatrix}$ where...

$X_1 \sim N(6,3)$

$X_2 \sim N(6,3)$

$X_3 \sim N(6,3)$

And $\vec{Y}$ would be $\begin{bmatrix}Y_1 & Y_2 & Y_3\end{bmatrix}$ where...

$Y_1 \sim N(2,15)$

$Y_2 \sim N(2,15)$

$Y_3 \sim N(2,15)$

Correlations can be summarized as...

$X_i$ is correlated with $Y_i$ in a fashion like $f_{X, Y}$.

$X_i$ is independent of $X_j$ where $i \ne j$.

$Y_i$ is independent of $Y_j$ where $i \ne j$.

$X_i$ is independent of $Y_j$ where $i \ne j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} 
f_{\vec X}(\vec x | \vec Y = \vec y) & = \frac{f{(\vec x, \vec y)}}{f(\vec y)} \\
& = \frac{\Pi_{n} f(x_i,  y_i)}{\Pi_{n} f(  y_i)} \; \text{because of independence} \\
& = \Pi_n f(  x_i | Y =  y_i)
\end{align}